# Android ListView into Tab

Tags: android, listview

i want to attach `ListView` into Tabs extends ListFragment. after running project and select tab i get this error :

`Unfortiunately, TSMS has stopped`

logCat result:

```
 08-22 04:23:00.974    1867-1867/ir.tsms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
```

in `onCreateView` function of `MyFriendsListFragment` i have this code to attach `Tab` :

`onTabSelected` in `MainActivity` class:

```
 @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
       // mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        switch ( tab.getPosition() ){
            case 1:
                MyFriendsListFragment simpleFriendsList = new MyFriendsListFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer, simpleFriendsList).commit();
                break;
        }
    }
```

`onCreateView` in `MyFriendsListFragment` class

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_fragment,
                            new String[] {
                                    "AAAAAAA",
                                    "BBBBBBB",
                                    "CCCCCCC",
                                    "DDDDDDD"
                            });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            /*return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);*/
            /*return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);*/
        }
```

list_fragment.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#dddd"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: is your fragment extending list fragment?

Comment: Change your ListView's id to `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 android:id="@+id/list"
```

to

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Also your using `setListAdapter` that means your Fragment will be extends with `ListFragment`.

Also change this.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                        .getBaseContext(), R.layout.urCustomLayout,
                        new String[] {
                                "AAAAAAA",
                                "BBBBBBB",
                                "CCCCCCC",
                                "DDDDDDD"
                        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

You need to pass Id of your `TextView` to your `ArrayAdapter`. If you are using custom layout then pass Id of your `textview ID` and if you are using default android layout then you should use `android.R.id.textView1`.

Comment: i'm sorry. i dont underestand me.my xml layout must be change?

Comment: @TuxWorld Can you show me ur screen shot of your listview?

Comment: after clicking on tab item i get error and ListView dont show. my layout is `list_fragment.xml` on my quastion

Comment: In your ListView want to display only Text means any label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59806/discussion-between-tuxworld-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 2):

android:id="@+id/list" is not the same as android.R.id.list "@+id/list" creates a new id in your package.
Correct id should be android:id="@android:id/list".